# Docker: Redis no config file specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I'm just curious why does my config doesn't get applied when running redis?

```
2023-07-25 19:42:28 1:C 25 Jul 2023 16:42:28.739 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

I know that I can just specify the config in the `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
`enter code here`command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
```

But why does my config don't work? In the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` in I have a file named `redis.conf` and in `docker-compose` I specify it as:

```
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    # command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis
```

my redis.conf:

```
bind 0.0.0.0
requirepass foobar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You're trying to mount a file on a directory. You need to fix your `volumes` stanza:

   ```
   volumes:
     - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis.conf
   ```
2. According the [image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis), you need to tell redis about your configuration file by setting `command` appropriately:

   ```
   command: [redis-server, /usr/local/etc/redis.conf]
   ```

Comment: Oh, the latest redis had a typo in the volume, previously it was just like that, but I was missing the /usr/local/etc/redis.conf in the command, I thought that it actually uses this path as a default. Also, do you mind if I ask what's the difference between using command as a string?

Comment: [This article](https://emmer.dev/blog/docker-shell-vs.-exec-form/) addresses that question.